# cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to perform a dispatch on 'logOutUser' in vuex store, and i'm getting the following error message in respone:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

deleteUser.vue (the component from which the dispatch action is not working):

```
<template>
    <v-dialog v-model="openDelete" persistent max-width="500px">
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
                <h4>Delete User</h4>
            </v-card-title> 
            <v-card-text>
                <h2>Are You Sure?</h2>
                <p>Deleting your user is a permanent action.</p>
                <br>
                <br>
                <v-btn
                 color="primary"
                 @click="deleteUser">
                 Delete User
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn
                 color="primary"
                 @click="openDelete = false">
                 Close
                </v-btn>  
            </v-card-text>  
        </v-card>   
    </v-dialog> 
</template>
<script>
import router from '../../router/index.js'
const firebase = require('../../firebaseConfig.js')
export default {
    data: function(){
        return {
            openDelete: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        deleteUser: function(){
            let user = firebase.auth.currentUser
            const docId = user.uid
            console.log("Trying to delete user ", docId)
            user.delete().then(function() {
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Error deleting user: ", error)
            });
            firebase.firestore.collection("users").doc(docId).delete().then(() => {
                        console.log('Trying to Log Out in Vuex')
                        this.$store.dispatch('user/logOutUser')
                        alert("User Deleted Successfully!")
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
                });
            router.push('hello')    
            this.openDelete = false
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import user from './modules/user'
import genre from './modules/genre'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        user,
        genre
    }
})
```

user.js:

```
const firebase=require('../firebaseConfig.js')

const state = {
    currentUser: null,
    userProfile: {}
}

const actions = {
        fetchUserProfile({commit, state}, uid){
            firebase.firestore.collection("users").doc(uid).get().then((doc)=>{
                commit('setUserProfile', doc.data())
            }).catch((error)=>{
                console.error(error)
            })
        },
        logOutUser({commit, state}){
            commit('setCurrentUser', null)
            commit('setUserProfile', {})
            console.log('Logged Out In Vuex')
        }
}

const mutations = 
    {
        setCurrentUser(state, val){
            state.currentUser = val
        },
        setUserProfile(state, val){
            state.userProfile = val
        }
    }

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

EDIT: Here's my main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store.js'
const firebase = require('./firebaseConfig.js')

Vue.config.productionTip = false

let app

firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(!app){
    /* eslint-disable no-new */
    app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router,
      store,
      components: { App },
      template: '<App/>'
    })
  }
});
```

I should mention that i'm dispatching this action from another component in my application, and it works perfectly fine from there.

Thank you!

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: For passerby: You can also get this warning if you incorrectly format the syntax of a method function. If you ue `fun: () => { this.X }` you mat not be in the appropriate context for `this`. Use `fun() { this.X}` instead.

Comment: For anyone running into this recently, please check that you have installed the version of vuex that matches your vue version. `vuex 3x <> vue 2x` `vuex 4x <> vue 3x`. If you run `npm install vuex` it will install version 4x by default. You must explicitly install vuex 3 `npm i vuex@3.6.2` to run with vue 2x

Answer (score 44):

That's because you probably didn't add `store` option to the root instance of Vue. By providing it you will be able to access store from all of root's child components. Therefore your root instance should look like this:

```js
import store from './store'

const app = new Vue({
  /* .. other properties .. */
  store
})
```

Now you can freely use `this.$store` within your components.

Comment: Hi! actually I am doing that. it's in my main.js file, i will add it to the original question.

Comment: @TomHarpaz Then I don't know. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: Should be accepted, in my case it solved the problem.

Answer (score 9):

It is unclear why it is not defined, and why it works when using modules, but not without modules. It could have something to do with the build process / transpiler. If `use` is actually a static method of the `Vue` class, then `$store` would be shared across all instances by installing the plugin via `use`, but this is not the case. It looks like `Vue` should be a class exported by the Vue module, but it seems to behave like an instance.

What I've found to work is one of the following (preferred being #3):

## 1. Call `Vue.use` wherever Vuex is used

```sh
src
├── App.vue
├── main.js <- Vue.use(Vuex)
├── router 
│   └── index.js <- Vue.use(Vuex)
└── store
    ├── myModule.js
    └── index.js <- Vue.use(Vuex)
```

```
// store/index.js
import Vue from "vue"; // This module's Vue is not the same instance as that referenced in main.js
import Vuex from "vuex";
import myModule from "./myModule.js";

// Required before creating new store instance
Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store(myModule);
```

```
// main.js
import Vue from "vue"; // this module's Vue is different from store/index.js' Vue
import Vuex from "vuex";
import app from "./App";
import router from "./router/index.js";
import { store } from "./store/index.js";

// this part is essential despite already calling Vue.use in store/index.js
Vue.use(Vuex);
// Or, see alternative below

new Vue({
    ...,
    router,
    store,
    components: { app }
});
```

## 2. Set `$store` for all instances of `Vue`

(As pointed out by yukashima huksay)

```sh
src
├── App.vue
├── main.js <- Vue.prototype.$store = store
├── router 
│   └── index.js
└── store
    ├── myModule.js
    └── index.js
```

```
Vue.prototype.$store = store;
```

## 3. Import global `Vue` instance into store and main

```sh
src
├── App.vue
├── global.js
├── main.js <- Vue.use(Vuex)
├── router
│   └── index.js
└── store
    ├── myModule.js
    └── index.js
```

```
// global.js
import vue from "vue";
export const Vue = vue;

// or if you're not using babel, you can use real javascript…,
export { Vue } from "vue";
```

```
// store/index.js
import { Vue } from "../global.js";
import vuex from "vuex";
import myModule from "./myModule.js";

Vue.use(vuex);

export const store = new vuex.Store(myModule);
```

```
// main.js
import { Vue } from "./global.js";
import store from "./store/index.js";
import router from "./router/index.js";
import app from "./App";

new Vue({
    ...,
    router,
    store,
    components: { app }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

do this

*let that = this;*

and use that to do the dispatching

*that.$store.dispatch(action)*

Answer (score 1):

So i've tried all of your solutions, and nothing seems to work out for me. I started to suspect that the problem is related to the fact that deleteUser.vue is not a direct child of App.vue. Anyone I did eventually imported store directly to the component:

```
import store from '../../store.js'
```

It solved the problem.
**I wonder if anyone know a more efficient way to solve this problem.**
Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: I had the same problem. I struggled for a day, until I read in your answer `I started to suspect that the problem is related to the fact that deleteUser.vue is not a direct child of App.vue.` And I noticed that the same thing is happening in my code and I remembered some things I had seen somewhere else a long time ago and boom! I found the solution which I've posted here. Hope it will help you too because importing store is really such a mess since you would lose all the benefits of mapActions, mapState, etc.

Answer (score 0):

On a other note

```
firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(!app){
    /* eslint-disable no-new */
    app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router,
      store,
      components: { App },
      template: '<App/>'
    })
  }
});
```

I bet you have this piece of code out of some tutorial because i was in that situation too but it will make your applicaton a lot slower on page reload because it will rerender everything everytime again.

I suggest you to use the onAuthStateChanged Event in your router (yes thats possible) and then check there for possible route blocks or not, will be a lot faster.

Im not home for code examples but i can send some later today if you want.

Comment: Yeah i took it from a tutorial. Thank you for your advice, i would love to see an example of that if that's possible:)

Comment: This implementation is for security reasons. -> To check if the user is logged in or not before the app fully loads.

Answer (score 0):

If we are going to follow app structure suggested by vueX.

Store will be injected automatically

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/structure.html

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be either not initialized store, or wrong `this` context.

For the purposes of debugging I'd try using `mapActions` helper 
[vuex.vuejs.org](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions-in-components):

```
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      add: 'increment' // map `this.add()` to `this.$store.dispatch('increment')`
    })

    // ...
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I even asked my own Stackoverflow question for it no no avail until I finally found the solution myself which I've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57910007/5120089)

## The content of the posted answer is as follows:

I was struggling with this problem for two days until I finally found the solution.

My problem was because I was using `$navigateTo` without specifying the frame, I was navigating the whole component. I discovered that store was only bound to the first component that is passed to the render function in main.js

**Here is how my main.js looked:**

```
new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h('frame', [h(store.state.is_logged_in ? Main : Login)]),
  created() {
    this.$store.commit('setNav', this.$navigateTo);
    if (this.$store.state.is_logged_in) {
      this.$store.dispatch('init');
    }
  },
}).$start();
```

I discovered that If is_logged_in was true `this.$store`, or `mapActions` etc only worked in `Main` and it's child components, otherwise it would only work in `Login` and it's child components. Then I was reading [This](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/key-value-local-storage-in-a-vue.js-nativescript-app-with-vuex) and saw the following code in the `store` code of the example:

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(Vuex);
const store = new Vuex.Store({...});
Vue.prototype.$store = store;
module.exports = store;
```

So I added the line `Vue.prototype.$store = store;` to my own store definition and finally my problem was solved. This really gave me such a hard time. Hope I can save somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, and it turned out I had imported Vue and Vuex with capitals, instead of with lowercased names. This is the proper way to import, but there is no error that tells you that this is a possible issue, so it is very hard to spot. I know it shouldn't be capital but anyone can mistype and there is no indication that this is the issue.

This is what I had: (SO DON'T COPY THIS CODE, IT WON'T WORK)

```
import Vue from 'Vue';
import Vuex from 'Vuex';
```

Correct Way:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex'; //<-- not Sentence case from '[V]uex' but '[v]uex'
```

Such a dumb error, but I'm sure others have had the same issue, so hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue because missed importing "store". Solved it as :

```
import store from './store'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
})
```