# How to manage the logged in state of user in nativescript vue?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I was wondering how to handle login/logout of the user so I did this:

```
store.commit('load_state');
store.subscribe((mutations, state) => {
  ApplicationSettings.setString('store', JSON.stringify(state));
});

new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h('frame', [h(store.state.is_logged_in ? App : Login)]),
  created() {
    this.$store.commit('setNav', this.$navigateTo);
    if (this.$store.state.is_logged_in) {
      this.$store.dispatch('init');
    }
  },
}).$start();
```

please note that loadstate initially loads the state from applicationsettings.
But the problem with this solution is that this.$store is not available in the child components of Login.vue
What would be the correct way to do this?

Please note that I'm not using vue-router here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was struggling with this problem for two days until I finally found the solution.

My problem was because I was using `$navigateTo` without specifying the frame, I was navigating the whole component. I discovered that store was only bound to the first component that is passed to the render function in main.js

**Here is how my main.js looked:**

```
new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h('frame', [h(store.state.is_logged_in ? Main : Login)]),
  created() {
    this.$store.commit('setNav', this.$navigateTo);
    if (this.$store.state.is_logged_in) {
      this.$store.dispatch('init');
    }
  },
}).$start();
```

I discovered that If is_logged_in was true `this.$store`, or `mapActions` etc only worked in `Main` and it's child components, otherwise it would only work in `Login` and it's child components. Then I was reading [This](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/key-value-local-storage-in-a-vue.js-nativescript-app-with-vuex) and saw the following code in the `store` code of the example:

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(Vuex);
const store = new Vuex.Store({...});
Vue.prototype.$store = store;
module.exports = store;
```

So I added the line `Vue.prototype.$store = store;` to my own store definition and finally my problem was solved. This really gave me such a hard time. Hope I can save somebody.