# Vuex store in Storybook undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, storybook

My main.js looks like this:

```
import './plugins';

import store from './store';

import FileUpload from './components/FileUpload';

export default {
    install(Vue) {
        Vue.component('file-upload', FileUpload);

        Vue.prototype.fileUploadStore = store;
    }
}
```

My FileUpload component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h1>Upload files</h1>
            <div class="dropbox">
                <input type="file" name="file"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'file-upload',

        created() {
            this.newUploadRequest();
        },

        methods: {
            newUploadRequest() {
                return this.fileUploadStore.dispatch('fileupload/newUploadRequest');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My story looks like this:

```
import FileUpload from '../resources/js/components/FileUpload';

export default {
  title: 'Components',
  component: FileUpload,
};

export const fileUpload = () => ({
  components: { FileUpload },
  template: '<file-upload/>'
});
```

And I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined
>       at VueComponent.newUploadRequest

Why is my store undefined?

Comment: check this post in case it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52482814/cannot-read-property-dispatch-of-undefined-in-vuex?rq=1

Comment: @AnuradhaKumari It's not realy relevant since I don't have a full vue app anywhere I just have a stand alone vue component that I am developing using Storybook

Comment: Where are you _using_ your plugin? Ie `import plugin from 'main.js'; Vue.use(plugin)`

Answer (score 1):

`Vue.prototype.fileUploadStore = store;` not performed, because you didn't execute `Vue.use(main.js module)`. You can try the following code:

#### Main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'; // -----①
import './plugins';

import store from './store';

import FileUpload from './components/FileUpload';

Vue.component('file-upload', FileUpload); // -----②
Vue.prototype.fileUploadStore = store; // -----③
```