# Vue: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined when submitting login form

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm getting the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined` error when I'm trying to submit the **Login.vue** form. I changed my `function()` to just `data()` etc, like SO answers suggested, but it didn't help...

**index.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import auth from './store/auth.module.js';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    //plugins: [createPersistedState({ storage: sessionStorage })],
    state: {  },
    mutations: {  },
    actions: {  },
    modules: { auth }
})
```

**main.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router';
import store from './store/auth.module';
import "./assets/css/tailwind.css";
import '@/assets/css/tailwind.css';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router, 
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

**auth-header.js**:

```
export default function authHeader() {
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

    if (user && user.accessToken) {
        return { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + user.accessToken };
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}
```

**user.service.js**:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import authHeader from './auth-header';

const API_URL = 'localhost:8088/testproject/api/users';

class UserService {
    getPublicContent() {
        return axios.get(API_URL + '/all');
    }

    getUserBoard() {
        return axios.get(API_URL + '?role=user', { headers: authHeader() });
    }

    getModeratorBoard() {
        return axios.get(API_URL + '?role=mod', { headers: authHeader() });
    }

    getAdminBoard() {
        return axios.get(API_URL + '?role=admin', { headers: authHeader() });
    }
}

export default new UserService();
```

**auth.service.js**:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8088/' +
    'testproject/api';

class AuthService {
    login(user) {
        return axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: API_URL + '/login',
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            data: {
                username: this.username,
                password: this.password
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                this.loginResponse = response;
                console.log("login response: " +
                    JSON.stringify(this.loginResponse));
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data));

                if (response.data.accessToken) {
                    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data));
                }

                return response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                /* ... */
                console.log("there was an error in request");
                console.log(err);

                return err;
            });
    }

    logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
    }

    register(user) {
        return axios.post(API_URL + '/signup', {
            username: user.username,
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password
        });
    }
}

export default new AuthService();
```

**Login.vue**:

```
<template>
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="sendLogin()"
          id = "login-form" class="hover:shadow-2xl
                cursor-pointer
                 transform
                duration-300
                hover:-translate-y-1
                rounded-lg shadow-lg
                w-4/5 lg:w-2/3 bg-white rounded shadow">

        <div class="pt-8 py-4 px-8 flex flex-col
                            content-center justify-center">
            <div class = "mb-4">Login</div>

            <div class="mb-6 ">
                <input v-model = "user.username" class="border
                        rounded w-3/4 py-2 px-3"
                       id="username"
                       type="username" placeholder="Your username">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-6 ">
                <input v-model = "user.password" class="border
                        rounded w-3/4 py-2 px-3"
                       id="password"
                       type="password" placeholder="Your password">
            </div>

            <div class="flex items-center justify-between mt-8">
                <button class="header bg-blue-700
                         hover:bg-blue-dark
                          font-bold py-2 px-4
                          rounded-full" type="submit">
                    Login
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>


<style lang="scss" scoped>...</style>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    import Profile from '../user/Profile.vue'
    import User from '../../models/user.js';

    export default {
        name: 'App',
        components: {
            Profile, User
        },
        data() {
            return {
                user: new User('', '')
            }
        },
        computed: {
            loggedIn() {
                return this.$store.state.auth.status.loggedIn;
            }
        },
        created() {
            if (this.loggedIn) {
                this.$router.push('/user/' + this.user.username);
            }
        },
        methods: {
            sendLogin() {
                this.$store.dispatch("auth/login", this.user).then(
                    () => {
                        this.$router.push({
                            name: "profile",
                            props: {
                                user: this.user
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    error => {
                        console.log('big error after login');
                    }
                );

                this.$router.push({
                    name: "profile",
                    props: {
                        username: this.username
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT**: After changing the import in **main.js** from `import store from './store/auth.module';` to `import store from './index.js';`
I get this error when trying to load any page (and the page doesn't load, all I get is a white screen):

[image]

Comment: Try access to store with vue object, `vue.$store.dispatch` is it works?

Comment: @Nanfish I get `error  'vue' is not defined  no-undef`  error. And the `vue` part is highlighted in IDE - `unresolved variable or type vue`

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, I'd say the issue is here in `main.js`

```js
// main.js
import store from './store/auth.module';
```

That appears to be importing one of your store modules which won't be a `Vuex.Store` instance.

In `main.js`, you need to import the store `index.js`

```js
// main.js
import store from './index.js'
```

By not importing `store/index.js`, you're also missing the all important

```js
Vue.use(Vuex)
```

Comment: I changed the store import to `import store from './index.js'` and now the `localhost` just doesn't load - it's a white screen and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined` error in console. The `auth.module.js` is located inside `store` folder. `store` folder and `main.js`, `index.js` are located in the same folder - IDE highlights it if I get a path wrong

Comment: @parsecer I don't see any `.getters` in your question code so can't really help there. Where does the error say it's occurring?

Comment: @parsecer I suspect the error is in your auth module. What does that look like?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check you are importing Vuex properly?

I feel the answer by phil is correct, but here is also some extra reading which might help solve the issue: [cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined in Vuex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52482814/cannot-read-property-dispatch-of-undefined-in-vuex/52483242)

Comment: No all `Vue` and `Vuex` `from` imports starts with lowercase - it's in the code I posted

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `main.js` file:

```
import store from '../yourPath';

vue.$store = store
```

this set the store object globally. so you can access it from any component by using `this`

Comment: This is absolutely not the way to do it

Comment: Sorry, but it now just looks like you copied Phil :(

Comment: `store` is not a plugin and a such, is not a candidate for `Vue.use()`. OP already has `Vue.use(Vuex)` anyway if that's what you were going for there

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your folder structure is like below.

store folder ->(contains) auth.module, index.js(the first code snippet you mentioned).

Now import store in to `main.js` like below.

```
import store from './store'
```

Now you're rest of the code should work.